# Set new controller after animation will finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

When application will launch, First `SplashScreen` was showing and it is using for splash screen(for animated purpose) when animation will be finished it should be push on another `MainViewController`.
Can Any one suggest me where is my mistake in code or how can i solve this.

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SplashScreen.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *splashView;
    }
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Here is my .m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [_window addSubview:obj_SplashViewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];


    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,480, 320, 50)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_offer.PNG"];
    [_window addSubview:splashView];
    [_window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:_window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}




- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    MainViewController *obj_MainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:obj_MainViewController];
}
```

Comment: Use the `block` - `[UIView animateWithDuration:....` instead of old style `[UIView beginAnimations:nil......`

Comment: can you tell me how? because i am fresher in ios.

Comment: and the code for splash screen was run successfully but after finishing the animation it will not move on secondviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Animation Block for iOS 4 and later](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)  :

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                         animations:^{
                         splashView.alpha = 0.0;
                         splashView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 50);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"completion block");
                              [splashView removeFromSuperview];
                               MainViewController *obj_MainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
                              [self.window setRootViewController:obj_MainViewController];
                         }];
    }
```

Comment: I don't disagree but I think your answer would be better with an explanation of why do it this way over the old way. This is mainly because they are new to this, and it always helps when someone explains something instead of just going here's some code use it.

Comment: my problem is not making animation view but my problem is i cant push on second view after animation will completed.

Comment: can u tell me what should i have to write in completion block so i can push on secnod viewcontroller?

Comment: i put your code in didfinishlaunch event but not working..even animation is also not working.

Comment: `splashView.frame` this could be causing issue. try define the frame before block getting called.

Comment: @BandishDave change animation duration and check it again .its working

Comment: If you'r doing with AutoLayout, `view.frame = ` doesn't work .

Comment: @KumarKL I have rechage the code but still not working ..how can i show you?